# Getting An Array from a function and converting it to a Variable

Tags: php, arrays

I got a function like this which pull product data the customers account:

```
 Am_Lite::getInstance()->getProducts()
```

get array of all defined in aMember products (product_id => title)

There is only 1 product for each customer so actually i don't need an array but this function gives an array unfortunately and not a single variable.

How can i convert this array to a single variable. Please help.

Comment: On a recent 'nuff PHP: `AM_lite....->getProducts()['product_id']`. on older phps, `$temp = AM__lite etc...; $product_id = $temp['product_id']`

Comment: Looks like the actual id may be the index.

Comment: I got the point and tried both options but it didn't work. Echo'd it too but it doesn't write anything. It should write something like "Package 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the function result to a variable, then index it to get the array element.

```
$products = Am_Lite::getInstance()->getProducts();
$product = $products[0];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate it is close to Marc's answer i guess i tried it and it doesn't work. Echo prints "array" . Maybe there is a problem with the function itself i don't know.

Comment: Sounds like it's returning a 2-dimensional array, so `$instances[0]` is another array.

Comment: My guess is that `$product` is an associative array containing the detailed information about that product. Use `var_dump($product)`, not `echo`.

Comment: var_dump($instances) worked it printed : filearray(3) { [2]=> string(4) "Standard" [3]=> string(12) "Professional" [4]=> string(8) "Ultimate" } From Here how can we proceed Never mind mate thanks for your help. I understand the problem i guess. This function doesn't return users package it returns all packages.

Comment: It really printed `filearray(3)`, not `array(3)`?

Comment: There's no `$product[0]` in that array. I don't know why the indexes start from `2`.

Comment: yeah array(3) sorry. Not filearray.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar actually you solved the problem. But the problem is diffrent.When i put $product[2] it printed "Standard" . Though it is not what i wanted. I think i will need api to get the users product. This won't let me do it. It returns general products which is useless=).

Answer (score 0):

`$singleProduct = Am_Lite::getInstance()->getProducts()[0];`

Comment: Tried this too mate didn't work. It was really simple and would be great if it worked. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to use PHP 5.4 or higher for this syntax to work.